# Grails Webservices Restfull

Tags: web-services, grails

I want to start to learn about using webservices, and the best way to start is by doing some small examples. I want to use Grails. I searched the web, but didn't find any usefull examples about implementing simple webservices in my code. I would like to do a RESTFULL webservice, which uses two numbers as input, calculate the sum and return an output with the value of the sum.

If possible, i would appreciate any tutorials about this, more simple the better.

Thanks in advanced,
OO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails is very easy to learn and a good choice.  The official Grails documentation covers web services well enough, in my opinion, to be a simple tutorial

http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/13.%20Web%20Services.html

For a more step by step, try here

http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/2477

Comment: i fint it hard to understand:p do you know any step-by-step concrete tutorial?